# Must Use Plugin Causing Query Error

Tags: php, loop, tags, array

I created an MU Plugin which will only display the posts from certain tags in the loop like  this:

```
function custom_tags( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'tag', array( 'custom', 'general' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_tags' );
```

It works fine when I remove the array and only check for 1 tag, but how do I get it to work with more than 1 tag like I'm trying to above?

The Error I'm getting is:

`Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /srv/users/s/wp-includes/query.php on line 1966`

`Warning: preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /srv/users/s/wp-includes/query.php on line 1967`

Updated Code:

```
$current = substr($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST], 0, -4);

function custom_tags( $query ) {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'general,{$current}' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_tags' );
```

Comment: [See the tag parameters section for `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters).

Answer (score 2):

As Milo ( and your errors ) point out: you're passing an array where a string is expected. According to [WP_Query tag parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters)

> Show posts associated with certain tags.
>
> - tag (**string**) - use tag slug.

To get around this you just need to pass a comma separated string:

```
function custom_tags( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'tag', 'custom,general' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_tags' );
```

Comment: @howdy-mcgee this works to check for 2 or more tags thanks ! if i wanted to add a dynamic tag as one of the possible tags how would i alter your code to do this? the variable is `$current`

Comment: @JoeBobby in PHP you can append variables to strings using double quotes, like this: `"custom,general,{$current}"`.

Comment: @howdy-mcgee I updated the bottom of my post with the updated code but i still cant get the dynamic tag to work, basically what its suppose to do is generate the domain name as `domain.com` and remove the last 4 characters which will remove the TLD and period

Comment: @JoeBobby in PHP single quotes `'like this'` define *absolute* strings which means everything inside of it will be treated as a string. On the other hand, double quotes `"like this"` create a string where you can process variables. You need to replace your single quotes with double quotes. You may also want to move your `$current` variable inside your function call.

Comment: @JoeBobby [Here's a bunch of good explanations from Stackoverflow which explain the different PHP strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) and of course the [PHP Strings Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: @howdy-mcgee im able to get this to work now but i just noticed if i change the tags like this ` $query->set( "tag", "test,test2" );` it removes the posts completely from the wordpress dashboard as u can see here: https://cloudup.com/c7DMdQqWe4U.  Is there any way to make sure the posts in the wordpress dashboard are always visible?

Comment: Try using if( is_admin() ) { return; }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33024/discussion-between-joe-bobby-and-howdy-mcgee).

Answer (score 1):

Create a proper [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), for example:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'people',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'bob',
    ),
),
```

But your code "update code" is going to fail for other reasons too.

1. `$current` is out of scope.
2. And your variable won't expand inside single quotes

The bare bones changes you need are:

```
function custom_tags( $query ) {
  $current = substr($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST], 0, -4);
  $query->set( 'tag', "general,{$current}" );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_tags' );
```

But as mentioned, I'd create a proper `tax_query`

```
function custom_tags( $query ) {
  $current = substr($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST], 0, -4);
  $tax = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'tag',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $current,
        'operator' => 'IN' // This is default
      ),
    );
  $query->set( 'tag', "general,{$current}" );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_tags' );
```

The operator can be changed to get different behavior:

> **operator** (*string*) - Operator to test. Possible
>   values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND', 'EXISTS' and 'NOT EXISTS'. Default
>   value is 'IN'.

And your code is going to run on every query on the site, just about. That is going to ***alter a lot of things***, and will certainly break things. You need to restrict it to only those locations you need it. I don't know exactly where or when this is supposed to run but this should be a start:

```
function custom_tags( $query ) {
  if (is_admin() 
    || $query->is_main_query()
  ) {
    return;
  }
  $current = substr($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST], 0, -4);
  $tax = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'tag',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $current,
        'operator' => 'IN' // This is default
      ),
    );
  $query->set( 'tag', "general,{$current}" );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_tags' );
```

Comment: @s-ha-dum getting 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR) in /srv/users/s/wp-content/mu-plugins/c.php on linloope 24` and after removing the || i get another error so not sure how to fix

Comment: There is a extra parents after `is_abmin()`